# how to find the volume of intersection between eleptic cylinder and cylinder?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> let C be the eleptic cylinder C = {$\frac{y^2}{4} + z^2\leq 1$}.
>
> let D be the cylinder {$x^2 + z^2 \leq 1$}
> find the volume of intersection of C and D

this is what i did :
$$V = \ \int_{z=-1}^{z=1}\int_{y=-\sqrt{4-4z^2}}^{y=\sqrt{4-4z^2}}\int_{x=-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{x=\sqrt{1-z^2}} 1{ \ dx}{\ dy}{\ dz} $$

$$= \ \int_{z=-1}^{z=1}\int_{y=-\sqrt{4-4z^2}}^{y=\sqrt{4-4z^2}}2\sqrt{1-z^2}{\ dy}{\ dz}=$$
$$= \ \int_{z=-1}^{z=1}2\sqrt{1-z^2}*2\sqrt{4-4z^2} {\ dz}= \int_{z=-1}^{z=1}4\sqrt{4z^4-8z^2+4} {\ dz}=\int_{z=-1}^{z=1}4\sqrt{(2z^2 -2)^2} {\ dz} =  \ 10\frac{2}{3}$$

why did i get negative volume ?
did i do it correctly ? or am i missing something

Comment: correct edited *

Comment: The integral looks right to me, and you certainly shouldn't get a negative answer.  Please post your calculations, so we can pinpoint the error.

Comment: i have posted extended calculation

Comment: I agree up to the very last equal sign.  How did you do the last integral?  I'm guessing you simplified $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ as $z^2-1$ instead of $1-z^2$.

Comment: the squrt of  $(2z - 2)^2  $ is $ 2z-2 $ so doing the integral it is $ z^3/3 - 2z $

Comment: yes was that incorrect ?

Comment: why should i take the other possibility of the squrt root

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct up to the last integral.  Recall that $\sqrt{z^2}=|z|,$ so $\sqrt{(z^2-1)^2}=|z^2-1|$  When $-1\le z\le1,$ we have $|z^2-1|=1-z^2,$ so you've got the sign wrong.

Comment: oh  i got it now thank you

Comment: It was my pleasure.